# angular ui-grid pagination v3.0.0-RC.18 not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How do you get pagination to work/controls to appear using angular ui-grid? Has anyone successfully done it?

I am aware of the [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination).

**Things I've tried that haven't worked:**

1. Using the tutorial as a guide.
2. Remaking the example outside of my project.
3. Using different versions of ui-grid; I've tried RC.12 - RC.21.
4. Using different versions of angularjs; I've tried 1.2.26 - 1.3.15.

I know that the `ui.grid.pagination` module is in the ui-grid js file I'm using and that it is being picked up by my controller. I tested this by changing the name of the directive in the ui-grid js file.

**Code from controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enablePagination: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: false,
            enablePaginationControls: true,
            paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
            paginationPageSize: 25,
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Processes</h1>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui.grid.pagination></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put `ui.grid.pagination` instead of `ui-grid-pagination` in the html.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! This is what happens when you copy and paste.